# Forgot sql password for a certain user (debian)

Tags: debian, sql

I have two sql users on my sql server: `root` and `bob`. I know the root password, but I forgot bob's password. How can I view/reset bob's password?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-user-password/ you mean this?

Comment: User which has privileges to update `user` table in `mysql` database can do that. `root` user can do that.  See the steps I've outlined in one of my answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1105982/295286

Comment: which db are you using ?

Comment: You need to be clearer - which SQL server are you using?  It could be MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about a MySQL server, and the `bob` user is a local user (`'bob'@'localhost'`), here's how to change the password of a MySQL user when you do not know the old password.

Login to MySQL as root, then issue one the following commands:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'bob'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('n3wp4ssw0rd');    # before v5.7.6
ALTER USER 'bob'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'n3wp4ssw0rd';        # v5.7.6 or newer
```

Then, reload the privileges table:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and you're good to go.